# Style the last table

Tags: css

I want to set a border on a table. My problem is: that on some pages one or more table are around the real one.

So my question is: How can i set the border only on the last table within others? Or when the table is alone, than this one?

Example:

```
<table>
.. This table should have borders..
</table>

<table> /* This one shouldn't have borders*/
  <tr><td>
    <table>
    .. This table should have borders..
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

Thank you for your help

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecto0jtd/

Ok, I think the Idea from anonymousxxx (http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/k0ntkt4d/1/) is the easiest way to solve this. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you should stop using tables for layout.

Comment: What makes you assume it's for layout? It could be complex data

Comment: I know, but i can change it! I can't insert classes, and the Layout is in Div. It's for List-Tables, where sometimes more than one table exists.

Comment: @AdamHughes - Fair question - because I recognise the pattern. The arbitrary level of nesting and the absence of borders (see the  table with column headings "Feature" and "Indication" here - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) mostly. The idea is that if you really had a complex data structure, you would need borders on the cells to make the data intelligible to the user.

Comment: I inserted an example in the question

Comment: The title does not correspond to the question (and this seems to have confused some people). Consider changing the title to describe the problem, e.g. “Set border on a table but only if it does not contain a table”.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it's not solution for your problem. I think your case not possible using css pure if element not want to have attribute for selector. Using javascript for selector last of tree element something like this http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/k0ntkt4d/1/

Answer (score 0):

The purpose seems to be to set border on a table but only if it does not contain a table. This is generally not possible without using extra markup, such as a `class` attribute. The reason is that in current CSS, you cannot select an element on the basis of its content.

The simplest approach is to set, say, `class="border"` on those tables that should have a border.

Or you could use `<table border>` and the selector `table[border]` in a rule that sets the specific borders you want (but the `border` attribute is regarded as bad/deprecated/nonconforming by some).

Answer (score -1):

In your example above,

```
    tr td table{
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Would style only tables nested within a row and data cell of a parent table.

Depends how many levels deep you want to go and if you only want to style nested tables or the last nested table? It also has broader browser support than pseudo-selectors which may be a factor depending on which browsers you need to support

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LCHyE for working example